# set default value other than options value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<select id="itemDepartment">

  <option value="1">Computer Accessories</option>
  <option value="2">Laptop</option>

</select>
```

the following attribute set the default value in drop down list

```
selected="selected"
```

but I want to select the default value other than options value i.e **Please Select Department** , when I click on the drop down list then  **Please Select Department** text disappear and options value appear ( as default behavior)

Comment: You will need javascript or some other client side script to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select id="itemDepartment">
    <option class="placeHolder" value=""> Please Select Department </option>  
    <option value="1">Computer Accessories</option>
    <option value="2">Laptop</option>
</select>​​​​​

$('#itemDepartment').focus(function() {
    $(this).find(".placeHolder").hide();
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).find(".placeHolder").show();
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nuaMb/)

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML do something like:

```
<select id="itemDepartment">
    <option value="">Please Select Department</option>
    <option value="1">Computer Accessories</option>
    <option value="2">Laptop</option>
</select>
```

Then in JQuery do.

```
$(function () {
    $("#itemDepartment").click(function () {
        $("#itemDepartment option:first").css("display", "none");
    });

    $("#itemDepartment").blur(function () {
        $("#itemDepartment option:first").css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the only way to get "**Please Select Department**" to show up in a `<select>` is to add it as an option, probably the first option

```
<select id="itemDepartment">
  <option value="">Please Select Department</option>
  <option value="1">Computer Accessories</option>
  <option value="2">Laptop</option>
</select>
```

Anything else will have to be a custom coded `<div>` with javascript or something that only looks like a `<select>`

Comment: You would need to use a script for hiding the default value. take a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10215021/601179)

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for a Placeholder plugin, like one of these:

- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/input-placeholder
- http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html
- https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+input+placeholder

Answer (score 1):

Just add a dummy value with the text you want.

```
<select id="itemDepartment">
  <option value="" selected="selected">[Please Select Department ]</option>
  <option value="1">Computer Accessories</option>
  <option value="2">Laptop</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: You would need to use a script for hiding the default value. take a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10215021/601179)

Comment: @gdoron, I know, but OP's has not mentioned he does not want the option again.

Comment: _"when I click on the drop down list then Please Select Department text disappear"_